# How I can see the console.log messages

Tags: console.log

How I can see the displayed messages for application running using console.log see below image example:

Additional data: I am running on WebLogic Server and I am using webssh, is a web application that I run using runtime of Java and open it in Internet Explorer.

Sample code of console.log:
[image: sample code of console.log]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the tools of internet explore from toolbar and select developer tools or you can press F12.

Then after you can see the inspection bar, right side of inspection bar has console. 
I think you can see that message at there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Developer tools are pretty powerful in every browser. Today we almost have a consensus on hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

Rigth click on the viewport then you will see **inspect elements** then a rectangular box will show up with many tabs and the **second one is the console** where you can see all of the `console.log()`